# How to write to file in maven and change target destinantion folder?

Tags: maven

I would like to write variable `${mercurialVersion}` (latest mercurial tag) to file in maven and also change target directory to be target/prod-latestMercurialTag/app.war. How can I do this?

This is the code I am using to populate `${mercurialVersion}` with the latest hg tag:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <phase>initialize</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>execute</goal>
        </goals>
        </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <script>hg parent --template {latesttag}</script>
                </properties>
                <source>
                    def command = project.properties.script
                    def process =
                    command.execute()
                    process.waitFor()
                    project.properties.mercurialVersion = process.in.text
                </source>
            </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I have tried:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.internetitem</groupId>
            <artifactId>write-properties-file-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>mercurialVersion</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>write-properties-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputFile>${baseDir}/src/main/resources</outputFile>
                        <filename>version.properties</filename>
                        <properties>
                            <property>
                                <name>version</name>
                                <value>${mercurialVersion}</value>
                            </property>
                            <property>
                                <name>artifactId</name>
                                <value>My Artifact ID is ${project.artifactId}</value>
                            </property>
                        </properties>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

But nothing gets into `${baseDir}/src/main/resources/version.properties` file ...

Thank you in advance.

Best regards,
mismas

Comment: Have you checked this: http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/

Comment: I have. Do you have any suggestions on how build versioning should be done? Is there a simple cookbook for standard situations? What am I doing wrong?